# After Delete and install fresh still app is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, icloud, nsdocumentdirectory

Hi I got something strange issue. just sharing with you and let me know your experience on this issue, if you have faced recently.

User have upgraded from iPhone 5 to iPhone 6plus. Before update he had done all the backup to iCloud(all the things with apps and their data also). after done backup he took new iPhone 6plus device and restore the device from the iCloud from latest backup..

Now the scenario is all my apps from one developer are empty (no data). event after delete and install fresh app from store issue is going same (no data)..

Technical details:
- I am using NSDocumentDirectory to store my app data (sqlite, images, etc.).
-  I am not using ExcludeBackup key because i need this to backup by default.

Now can you all share your experience with me, if you have faced this issue recently.

Comment: When user delete app it also remove everything in the Document folder that come with your app, if you want it to persist even after user delete you have to store it in icloud storage or in your own server

Comment: @Tj3n: I am aware of this things.but if you know NSDocumentDirectory is automatically backup by iOS..so this is my scenario.